# JSON Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying to read JSON through jQuery/AJAX but so far it keeps returning undefined.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/ajax/retrieve.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("#items").html(data);

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        console.log(key + ' ' + val);
        $("#items").append('\
          <div class="item-section" id="' + key + '">\
          <div class="item">\
            <h3>' + val.current_status + '</h3>\
          </div>\
          </div>\
        ');
      });
    }
  });
```

Inside the console the output for the log inside the iteration is as follows, but when I try to add val.current_status in the HTML it just says "undefined":

```
0 {"id":"4","creation_date":"15 Jan 2015 - 07:32 AM","current_status":"Pending", [... and so on]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may be helpful to see how you are setting (echoing) the values in `retrieve.php`.

Comment: It's taking data from a number of tables, but from the main table it is just `$array['current_status'] = $status;` - this array is then pushed to the main `$data` array using `array_push($data, json_encode($array));` - then finally `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Why are you using `key + ' ' + val`? Why not `console.log(key, val)`. The difference is that if your JSON is being returned as a string (rather than an object), you'd have no way of knowing from your console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your console is outputting "`{"id":"4","creation_date":"15 Jan 2015 - 07:32 AM","current_status":"Pending"...`" then your "object" is a string, not a JSON object. Check out the example below. You should be seeing "`[object Object]`" in your console window.

My guess is that your server is accidentally converting the JSON to a string value at some point, complete with escaped quotation marks, etc. Perhaps you've called the JSON serializer twice, somehow?

This is why you shouldn't attempt to convert data to a string in your console. You're thinking of it like it's a C console, where everything has to be a string to understand it. Browser consoles are much smarter and more more interactive than that... you should output the actual value so that you can see its type and work with the properties, etc:

```
console.log( key, val );
```

```js
  var key = 0,
      val_str = "{\"id\":\"4\",\"creation_date\":\"15 Jan 2015 - 07:32 AM\",\"current_status\":\"Pending\"}",
      val_obj = {"id":"4","creation_date":"15 Jan 2015 - 07:32 AM","current_status":"Pending"};

  $( '#str' ).text( key + ' ' + val_str );

  $( '#obj' ).text( key + ' ' + val_obj );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="str"></div>
<div id="obj"></div>
```

Comment: Checking the console showed it was returning a string rather than an object - so a small tweak to the PHP and it's now working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Iterate Array of Objects**

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {

    $.each(val, function(k, v) {
        // do something 
    });

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still returning undefined for me.

Comment: I think you're right, but this is throwing an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '221' in {"id":"4","creation_date":"15 Jan 2015 - 07:32 AM" [... and so on]` - Would this require parsing the JSON beforehand?

Comment: Yes it would but that should be done in the AJAX call.  Use dataType method